# Connecting the secondary side of ignition coil to earth

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, automotive, emc, grounding

[image]

I have an ignition system used for some application.

During the testing I found that spark plug is producing EMI due to spark occurrence and high voltage is traveling through the wire.

So to suppress the noise signals, I connected the secondary end connection to the earth (through electrical junction box.)  But when I turned on the setup, the equipment (RPS) which connected on the same line (connected on the same junction box) is disturbed (glitches in display,) within few seconds RPS is blown off (something is burned inside the RPS).

I am not able find the exact problem but during the testing I tried moving the earth connection near to the secondary end, suddenly an arc is jumped from secondary end to earth connection.

Comment: What does "RPS" stand for?

Comment: @JRE Regulated power supply

Comment: The other side of the "Junction Box" is your Mains power?

Comment: @Tyler yes connected to mains supply

Comment: Automotive ignition coils have an internal connection between the negative ground sides of the primary and secondary coils, and then to the metal case. They also use a high voltage wire with built-in suppressor resistance. Or you could add a high-voltage series resistor in the meg-ohm range.

Comment: @HEMARAJJ - Hi, I have "rolled-back" (i.e. "undone") where you deleted the diagram in your question, as that is required in order for readers to understand the question.  Since this question has no answers currently, then if you don't want the question to exist, you can delete the whole question. See [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Comment: I have flagged this question for mod attention, as the OP is repeatedly vandalising the question by removing the diagram.

Comment: RPS without any image and some association with grounded ignition system recalls an old idea: a robbery prevention system. In the past cars invariably presented there's people who have something valuable that could be taken off for better usage. Only open the door or smash a window and do some persuading gestures with a knife. Car owners tried to keep local procurement agents off by placing a wire from a spark plug H.V. wire to the ground under the car. If a procurement agent touches the car one plug is shorted but the rest work and the engine doesn't stop.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that, with the hot end of the secondary earthed, the high voltage (>12kV) reversed through the primary into the regulated power supply resulting in the transformer getting burnt due to insulation failure.

It is imperative that you disconnect the power supply from the mains immediately. With the insulation having failed, it would be extremely hazardous to handle it.

Take care!